# Passing Model object to JSON

Tags: json, r, model

I am trying to put a statistical model object into a JSON file, which will then be passed to and from an API. However, JSONs obviously do not work with raw model objects, as the model objects contain class types that the toJSON() function (in the jsonlite package) cannot convert.

Here's a simple example using some pre-packaged data from the MASS library:

```
library(MASS)
library(jsonlite)
utils::data(anorexia, package = "MASS")

anorex.1 <- glm(Postwt ~ Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt),
                family = gaussian, data = anorexia)

export <- toJSON(anorex.1)
```

This yields the error "Error: No method asJSON S3 class: lm".

Any help in getting this model object into a JSON structure would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution, if you only need some information from the `glm` object, might be to use `toJSON` on a list that you create from elements of the object. For example you can get the coefficients, coefficient names, and residuals using:

```
toJSON(list(coefficients=anorex.1[["coefficients"]],
            coefNames=names(anorex.1[["coefficients"]]),
            residuals=anorex.1[["residuals"]]))
```